# Trouble with finding Automation Id for Border inside ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, coded-ui-tests

I have **DataTemplate** for a class which follows following hierarchy

[image]

I have given **AutomationId** to each of these Controls.
when I try to detect the highlighted border using **Coded UI Test builder**, i am unable to find it. whereas i am directly getting Checkbox inside one of its child control.

I am not able to automation to this parent control(Border) due to this problem.
If I place **GroupBox** instead of Border I am able to get this control.

posted actual datatemplate [Here](http://tunetowpf.blogspot.in/2014/07/blog-post.html)

please help out.

Comment: Try using the cross-hairs tool, ie the assertion generator. Find items near the required border then us the four arrow keys to navigate around the controls that Coded UI can see.

Comment: But I wonder why Border control is not visible when it is included in DataTemplate?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the Coded UI Test Builder's cross hairs to get to the level.  Just point to it with the cross hairs, and when it points you to the checkbox, use the arrows to navigate the tree.

[image: Coded UI Test Builder snapshot]

Another suggestion would be to use C# to manually add it to your map.  This would be done by specifying an identifying property for the control.  However, I think you may have trouble using `AutomationProperties.Name` or `AutomationProperties.AutomationId`.  You'd have more luck adding an the [Name property to the border](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx) and identifying the control with that.

So:

```
public HtmlControl BorderOrangeBorder
{
    get
    {
        HtmlControl target = new HtmlControl([browser]);
        target.SearchProperties["name"] = "OrangeBorder";
        return target;
    }
}
```